# Make a sub-struct inherit the initialization?

Tags: c++, struct

So this is a simplified version what I have to deal with at work. Currently, the head struct does not have a ack or nak variable. I need it to have one that is initialized to something so that I can check if it changed later. There are other structs that inherit from the head that have a ack/nak variable (too many for me to go back and delete them.

The point is, I need for msgnak to initialize it's

```
char nak
```

to 'y'. I know it doesn't work as it is right now, is there any way to make it work?

```
struct head
{
    char ack;
    char nak;
    head() : ack('x'), nak('y') {}
};

struct msgnak : head
{
    char nak;
};
```

edit: thanks for the information guys. It seems that what I want to do isn't possible with the way C++ works.

Comment: In `msgnak` put `msgnak(): nak('y') {}`. I assume you intentionally wanted `msgnak::nak` a separate variable from `head::nak`

Answer (score 0):

`nak` field in the subclass `msgnak` is *hiding* the `nak` field of the base class head.

If you don't re-declare `nak` in the sub class, it will be initialized to 'y' because the base derived constructor is implicitly called before the derived constructor.

Hiding a field of a base class(or struct) isn't, generally, a good idea. The layout of your base class will end up with 3 fields. You are not overriding it, just hiding.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to understand here that in your code example every object of type msgnak contains two member variables 'nak':

```
msgnak obj;       // implicitly initializes the nak of head to y
obj.nak = 'z';    // assigning the nak of msgnak (not initialized yet)
cout << obj.nak;  // printing the nak of msgnak
cout << ((head *)(&obj))->nak;  // the nak of head
```

will print out "zy", because of the two 'nak' members.  Most likely the additional member nak in struct msgnak was not what you wanted?